# What's the time complexity of Monte Carlo Tree Search?

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, montecarlo, tree-search

I'm not sure whether this question should go on stackoverflow or cs.stackexchange.com, so please let me know if I should move it.

I'm trying to find the time complexity of Monte Carlo Tree Search (MCTS). Googling doesn't help, so I'm trying to see how far I get calculating it myself.

It does four steps for `n` iterations, or before the time runs out. So we'll have

> O(n*(selection+expansion+simulation+backpropagation))

Expansion just adds a child to the currently selected node. Assuming you're not using a singly linked list or something like that to store tree children, this can happen in constant time, so we can exclude it:

> O(n*(selection+simulation+backpropagation))

Given the branching factor `b`, and `t` total number of nodes in the tree, I'm assuming the selection phase runs in O(b*log<sub>b</sub> t), because the depth of the tree is log<sub>b</sub> t, and at every depth, we go over b children.

So our time complexity becomes

> O(n*(b*log<sub>b</sub>t+simulation+backpropagation))

Backpropagation takes time proportional to the depth of the tree as well, so that becomes:

> O(n*(b*log<sub>b</sub>t+simulation+b*log<sub>b</sub>t))

But now I'm not sure how to add  the simulation phase to this.

Comment: Yeah, this is more a `cs` question. This isn't actual programming, it's CS/math theory.

Answer (score 0):

> After we have selected a node to expand, we expand the node into m
>   random children rather than a single child. Furthermore, rather than
>   simulating out the child state only once, we simulate each child state
>   k times.

- m is number of children of a node
- k is number of simulations of a child

> The **runtime of the algorithm can be simply be computed as O(mkI/C)**
>   where m and k are the same as before, and I is the number of
>   iterations and C is the number of cores available.

Reference:

http://stanford.edu/~rezab/dao/projects/montecarlo_search_tree_report.pdf