# How branching factor affects complexity of Monte Carlo Tree Search?

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, montecarlo

I was reading: [What's the time complexity of Monte Carlo Tree Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724201/whats-the-time-complexity-of-monte-carlo-tree-search)

Where it says:

> The runtime of the algorithm can be simply be computed as O(mkI/C)
> where m and k are the same as before, and I is the number of
> iterations and C is the number of cores available.

According to this definition let's suppose we had a game with a branching factor of b then made some changes to that game so the new branching factor is 5b.
How does this affect the run time complexity of MCTS?

From what I see if we run in same environment this doesn't change the run time (as the equation doesn't include b - branching factor) but that doesn't make sense to me...